# how to type linear algebra symbols

Tags: ubuntu, math

How do I type the symbols for linear algebra on Ubuntu?

Are there any programs that use them? ( I understand this is trivial basket weaving. Whats the fastest way! )

Comment: What do you want to do with linear algebra symbols? Make printed documents with mathematical content? Make content that you distribute on the web? Make presentations? Just draw the symbol for illustration purposes? Or type the Unicode character in any application?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to install TeXLive before.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

and use some editor, texmaker, for example. After, you can look for info here [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Install LaTeX on Debian or Ubuntu:

```
sudo aptitude install texlive-latex-base
```

If you use Emacs, in `.emacs`, you could put:

```
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq TeX-save-query nil)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

Then, as an example formulae (the integral):

```
\(\int\limits_a^b {f(x)dx} = [F(x)]_a^b = F(b)-F(a)\)
```

Check out some [stuff](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/latex/) I've done. Also, check out the [SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you want latex which is the standard way of displaying math symbols.  Try lyx

```
http://www.lyx.org/
```

There are other Latex editors out there.